# Notify search engine crawlers about user generated content so that our rankings are not biased by keywords used by users

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, keywords, meta-tags

Is there a meta tag or a way to notify crawlers that a page is generated by the user?

To clarify the issue, We have a website already promoted by SEO and we want to add dynamic user generated content (ex: a user profile page) and we want it to be indexed but not to affect our keyword density.

Comment: Why should user generated pages *not* affect the keyword density? Or in other words: These seem to be two different issues: a) mark a page as user-generated, b) index a page without affecting keyword density. I guess your real intention is b), not a)? Or would you be interested in a solution for a) without b)?

Comment: b) is more of what I'm looking to resolve. And a) is what I think can achieve it (but I might be wrong)

Comment: Why do you think that user generated pages would hurt your site?  You need to police your user generated content for spam, scraped content, and nonsense, but user generated content can be great for your rankings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the original question: no there is no way to mark a page as user-generated content.

But "keyword density" is not a site-wide metric. Adding user-generated content will not affect the keyword density of your other pages and will not harm the ranking of your site (unless there is a large amount of spam).

Adding some UGC to existing pages is very unlikely to harm the pages either.

Comment: Thanks for you response, are there any articles or further information to support your answer?